# Why multiple errors when return a struct in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, struct, overloading

I am having problems returning a struct.

I created a function **currentPeriodCharges** that would perform some calculations and return results for their use in another function.

one of the errors include: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

any thoughts?

here is the struct:

```
typedef struct{
float cpCharges[3];
int cUsage[2];
}mystruct;
```

here is the function:

```
mystruct currentPeriodCharges (char a,int b,float c){
mystruct retVal;
int c=100;

if(a=='C'||a=='c'){
    retVal.cpCharges[2]=b*rate[1];
    retVal.cUsage[0]=0;
    retVal.cUsage[1]=0;
    retVal.cpCharges[0]=0;
    retVal.cpCharges[1]=0;
    return retVal;
}
    else{
        if(a=='R'||a=='r'){
            if(b<100){
                retVal.cpCharges[2]=b*rate[0];
                retVal.cUsage[0]=0;
                retVal.cUsage[1]=0;
                retVal.cpCharges[0]=0;
                retVal.cpCharges[1]=0;
                return retVal;
            }
                else{
                    if(b>100){
                        retVal.cUsage[0]=c;
                        retVal.cUsage[1]=b-retVal.cUsage[0];
                        retVal.cpCharges[0]=retVal.cUsage[0]*rate[0];
                        retVal.cpCharges[1]=retVal.cUsage[1]*rate[1];
                        return retVal;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: do you have more than one function with same name and list of arguments ?

Comment: no, the function **currentPeriodCharges** is the only function with that name and list of arguments.

Comment: does your compiler indicate where this error has occurred ?

Comment: Yes, a red squiggly line is placed under the function **currentPeriodCharges**. it also mention errors that have to do with the arrays in the function as well;

Comment: 'mystruct' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef,
.cpCharges' must have class/struct/union
       type is ''unknown-type''

Comment: have you considered this : `    typedef struct mystruct{
    float cpCharges[3];
    int cUsage[2];
    }mystruct;`

Comment: yes, i just did; it increased the errors

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. The error suggests you've defined the name `mystruct` more than once, sometimes as a class/struct name and other times as a typedef name.

Comment: yes, i created an object of mystruct 2 times after the creation of the struct...
mystruct val;
//val was created to collect was is returned
mystruct retVal;
//retVal was created to manipulate the variables in the struct; assign values to the variables in the struct

Comment: can i get some help please? anyone?

Comment: Try to empty the currentPeriodCharges body as much as you can. Post the overloaded function. Try to build a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second error:

> 'mystruct' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef

is more meaningful here. The real problem must be right before the line
`mystruct currentPeriodCharges (char a,int b,float c)`.

In most cases is just missing semicolon, but it can be any error before that line.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, so this is an "answer")

I think we need to see more of this code.

I'm also curious as to why we don't see a reported error of

```
Error   1   error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'c'
```

where the parm `float c` is in the function header and the `int c=100;` is in the body of text